# Generate regular expression for following string

Tags: regex

**"https://github.com/username/MyApp.git" or "git@github.com:username/MyApp.git"**

I'm trying to generate regular expression for above two urls as follows.

1. It should match with start string with https and end with .git
2. It should check the condition for both case sensitive

I tried this

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: yes I have tried this  ^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at the end of the expression

```
^(https:\/\/|git+)@?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})(:|[\/\w \.-]*)*\/?(.git)$
```

Hope this works